# How can i make my MLX90614ESF scan temperature after the MFRC522 scans the RFID tag?

Tags: arduino-uno, rfid, temperature-sensor, infrared

```
//THIS IS THE RFID CODE

#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define RST_PIN         9           // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
#define SS_PIN          10          // Configurable, see typical pin layout above

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance

//*****************************************************************************************//
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);                                           // Initialize serial communications with the PC
  SPI.begin();                                                  // Init SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();                                              // Init MFRC522 card
    //shows in serial that it is ready to read
}
//*****************************************************************************************//
void loop() {
  // Prepare key - all keys are set to FFFFFFFFFFFFh at chip delivery from the factory.
  MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;
  for (byte i = 0; i < 6; i++) key.keyByte[i] = 0xFF;
  //some variables we need
  byte block;
  byte len;
  MFRC522::StatusCode status;
  //-------------------------------------------

  // Reset the loop if no new card present on the sensor/reader. This saves the entire process when idle.
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
    return;
  }

  // Select one of the cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
    return;
  }


  byte buffer1[18];

  block = 4;
  len = 18;

  //------------------------------------------- GET FIRST NAME
  status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, 4, &key, &(mfrc522.uid)); //line 834 of MFRC522.cpp file
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    return;
  }

  status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Read(block, buffer1, &len);
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    return;
  }

  //PRINT FIRST NAME
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; i++)
  {
    if (buffer1[i] != 32)
    {
      Serial.write(buffer1[i]);
    }
  }
  Serial.print(" ");

  //---------------------------------------- GET LAST NAME

  byte buffer2[18];
  block = 1;

  status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, 1, &key, &(mfrc522.uid)); //line 834
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    return;
  }

  status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Read(block, buffer2, &len);
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    return;
  }

  //PRINT LAST NAME
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    Serial.write(buffer2[i] );
  }

  //----------------------------------------

  delay(1000); //change value if you want to read cards faster

  mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();
  mfrc522.PCD_StopCrypto1();
}
//*****************************************************************************************//

// AND THIS IS THE MLX90614 CODE 
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MLX90614.h>

Adafruit_MLX90614 mlx = Adafruit_MLX90614();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  mlx.begin();  
}

void loop() {
  
  Serial.print("*\Body Temperature = "); Serial.print(mlx.readObjectTempC()); Serial.println("*C");

  Serial.println();
  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: Please add some text to your question.  What is happening, why it is not what you expected to happen and what you would like to happen.  Humm, from the looks of it, this code likely does not compile because you have multiple functions using the same name.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have simply concatenated the code from the RFID tag Sketch and the code from Temperature Sketch together.  This will not work as both programs contain identically named functions. Specifically "setup()" and "loop()".  What you need to do is integrate the code for each "setup()" function into one "setup()" function.  Similarly, you need to do the same with the "loop()" functions.

Assuming you only want to scan the temperature after you have successfully recovered data from the RFID tag, place the Temperature Sketch loop code immediately before the delay in the RFID tag code.

Comment: Someone may actually code a solution up for you @Ace Canacan.  I think you should try for your self first.  Also, it is always better if you try something before asking your question here.  More people will be willing to help if they see you have tried a few times before asking a question.